# "wasm32-unknown-unknown target is not supported"-error while integrating try-runtime

Tags: try-runtime

Using [this guide](https://docs.substrate.io/how-to-guides/v3/tools/try-runtime/) to integrate `try-runtime` on my node i get the error about get random not building for wasm.

```
  error: the wasm32-unknown-unknown target is not supported by default, you may need to enable the "js" feature. For more information see: https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support
     --> /home/simson/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/getrandom-0.2.3/src/lib.rs:219:9
      |
  219 | /         compile_error!("the wasm32-unknown-unknown target is not supported by \
  220 | |                         default, you may need to enable the \"js\" feature. \
  221 | |                         For more information see: \
  222 | |                         https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support");
      | |________________________________________________________________________^

  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `imp`
     --> /home/simson/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/getrandom-0.2.3/src/lib.rs:246:5
      |
  246 |     imp::getrandom_inner(dest)
      |     ^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `imp`
```

I get this error when I enable `frame-try-runtime` on the second line below (In `[features]` section of `runtime/Cargo.toml`)

```
try-runtime = [
    "frame-executive/try-runtime",
    "frame-try-runtime",
    "frame-system/try-runtime",
]
```

I suspect the root cause of this is not related to wasm but rather that some dependency is leaking std code into the wasm build. What kind of miss-configuration should I be looking for to find this problem?

Comment: Did you make sure to make `try-runtime` optional and enable it with `std`? Can you share a diff of the changes you made to your node leading to this error?

Comment: I will try to boil it down to a minimal reproducible error, hold on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the latest Rust nightly has broken our Wasm builds.

There have been other reports of this issue here:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/10767

And the fix is coming in here:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/10837

Comment: No it can't be the tool chain, I can build the same sha withou the changes but this: looks like the problem sudipghimire533 commented 10 days ago
Usually this is due to missing some entry features section like

[features]
std = [
    'sp-std/std',
    # if some crate entry is missing here
]
Or you might be missing default-features = false in some toml file

Straight-forward way to resolve this would be compare the commit where everything was fine and carefully analyse the changes in all Cargo.toml file keeping in mind above-mentioned 2 things.