# Substrate Node v3.0 getrandom Compilation error

Tags: error, compilation

The error described below is produced when attempting to compile the node upgraded to v3. The Cargo.toml files indeed specify the js feature; the issue occurs when compiling packages within Cargo.lock, which include the getrandom package. As getrandom is the direct dependency of those packages, I am not sure how to specify js feature for them as well.
Please let me know what can be done to resolve this issue.

Compiling getrandom v0.2.6
error: the wasm32-unknown-unknown target is not supported by default, you may need to enable the "js" feature. For more information see: https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support
--> /Users/raid/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/getrandom-0.2.6/src/lib.rs:235:9
|
235 | /         compile_error!("the wasm32-unknown-unknown target is not supported by 
236 | |                         default, you may need to enable the "js" feature. 
237 | |                         For more information see: 
238 | |                         [https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support"](https://docs.rs/getrandom/#webassembly-support%22));
| |________________________________________________________________________^

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because no more active.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that this error comes from the new try-runtime feature, which wasn't correctly added to the substrate-node-template.

At least when I run `cargo check --all-features` on a fresh substrate-node-template then it returns `cannot find trait TryRuntime in crate frame_try_runtime`.

I fixed this by going into `runtime/Cargo.toml` and adding the following. This would exclude the standard library to properly work with WASM.

```
std = [
    ...
    "frame-try-runtime/std",
    ...
]
```

Please double check if you have the following package in your `runtime/Cargo.toml` with `default-features = false`:

```
frame-try-runtime = { ..., default-features = false, git = "https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git", ... }
```

Make sure that you don't have the `try-runtime-cli` dependency in `runtime/Cargo.toml`.

If this doesn't help, then please try to give additional information about how to reproduce the error. Which substrate-node-template version did you run?

Comment: I created a pull request for this [here](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/pull/348).

Comment: Also look at [this](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/46/wasm32-unknown-unknown-target-is-not-supported-error-while-integrating-try-run)